# How to import existing source code with multiple branches into git

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a HTML/PHP website which is currently not in any source control. I have two different folders a development and live folder. The development folder is where I create new features and the live folder is the source which is actually used for real users. I want to represent dev and live as two different branches in git (I think this is the right way to model it, I'm open to other suggestions tho). I want to make sure once I've set-up these two branches I will be able to take advantage of git merge (dev --> live) to move features from dev to live once they are completed/tested.

I'm not sure how I would actually go about setting these two branches up correctly as they are already existing in my folders and are somewhat different. They have different paths, different database connection info, etc. This would not normally concern me if the project was tracked in git from the beginning because then the dev and live branches would naturally have branched off in the history and have some common ancestor commit. I want to make sure merge will work for bringing features over but not overwrite the fixed paths, database connection info etc.

I am using Bitbucket and SourceTree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that you have two directories (folders): `/dev` and `/live`. You are correct to try to put them in separate branches. But, in addition, you will want to make two separate *repositories* for the future. You may also want to have a central repository so that you can collaborate with others, but if you do not have that need right now you can just fetch changes into the "live" repository from the "dev" repository.

> They have different paths, different database connection info, etc.

This type of stuff should **not** be tracked at all. All properties files should be ignored using  the .gitignore file. Please read up on that in the [documantion for .gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

The commands I have listed below are simplified a bit. If you have many discrete pending changes, you may want to create more than one branch directly off of master, and only add files to the index that belong on a particular branch. This is especially true if you are not planning on migrating at the same time. For your first attempt, though, it might be easier to test dev until it can be fully moved into live, and start a better workflow after that.

```
cd /live
git init
git add <...> #My suggestion is that you add files manually, so that you do not add configuration files by mistake
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
cd /dev
git init
cd /live
git remote add dev /dev/.git
git push dev master # this is the only time you should push from live to dev
cd /dev
git checkout -b develope
git add <...> #same warning as before
git commit -m 'Initial Development Commit'
```

After this point you should check out a new branch every time you work on a new feature or bug-fix. When you have concluded testing in the dev directory, merge your feature into master. Then:

```
cd /live
git fetch dev master
```

There are other things you may want to do, such as tagging releases, but I think that would already be beyond the scope of your question.